# Set all coloured pixels in an image to Bright[255]?, OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm doing a project which involves coloured pictures of signs around a campus area. I need to grab the sign and label the numbers on the sign.

[image]

So far I have been taking the image, converting it to grayscale, filtering/sharpening it. Then thresholding to grab the sign. This works most of the time because the sign is black and the text is white.

[image]

However there are some images that have dark shadows in them combined with bright sunlight,making some of the background section within shadow darker than the black sign.

[image]

Because of this there is no Thresh holding value that can isolate the sign from the background.

So my question is, is there a way to preprocess the image so that all coloured sections, even really dark ones, (like a dark brown/red) are set to 255. And then based on a threshold value set all black sections to 0 and white sections to 255.

I know that whites, blacks and greys all have similar  bgr values so surely there should be a way to do this.

Thanks and sorry for not being able to link the images directly I don't have enough points.

Comment: Have you investigated Adaptive Thresholding or Otsu binarization? There is a great [tutorial here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html).  If you are going to do OCR to find text in these images, you'll probably have to invert them, because OCR algos like black text on white background.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I use adaptive thresholding and Otsus binarization also on every picture, and it helps with some of them, but not the ones with shadows that I mentioned in the posts, here are some examples.

Oh I pressed enter which saved the post, I will edit this with examples when I get them in 5-10 mins.

Comment: Examples:
see the 305, pic when used with otsus, the too dark shadows mess with the otsus threshold formula so it doesn't work, and adaptive thresholding doesn't grab the edges properly when dark shadows cover the sign, the other solution below seems pretty good though.

https://imgur.com/a/7xEciSd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the image to HSV - Hue, Saturation, Value. Hue defines the color, Saturation the intensity of the color, and Value the brightness. Black/gray/white values have little saturation, so you can use that property to remove the background.

This is a HSV visualization:
[image]
You want all the values in the 'core' of the cylinder.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    # load image
    img = cv2.imread("0hfSa20.png")
    # Convert to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # define range wanted color in HSV
    lower_val = np.array([0,0,0]) #full black RGB = 0,0,0
    upper_val = np.array([179,58,255]) # all hue, all value, cap saturation at 58

    # Threshold the HSV image to get only grayish colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

    # apply mask to image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)

    # display image
    cv2.imshow("Res", res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

HSV is also very good for filtering color. If you want to experiment with values and learn to understand HSV, [this script](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator) is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I like @J.D.s Answer. Very clever.

As an alternative solution, Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding works a treat for me (so does regular Adaptive Thresholding). But with an unexpected twist: I used a *negative* constant `C`:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('311.png', 0)
image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                              cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 17, -6)
cv2.imwrite('311_thresh.png', image)

image = cv2.imread('109.png', 0)
image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,
                              cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 17, -6)
cv2.imwrite('109_thresh.png', image)
```

311_thresh.png:

[image]

109_thresh.png:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, that ended up looking much nicer than I expected, I'll try this on the rest of the sample pics, thanks man